# Regex gurus! here's a teaser: mixed thousands separators and csv's

Tags: php, regex

I've got  a string like...

```
"labour 18909, liberals 12,365,conservatives 14,720"
```

...and i'd like a regex which can get rid of any thousands separators so i can pull out the numbers easily. Or even a regex which could give me a tidy array like:

```
(labour => 18909, liberals => 12365, conservatives => 14720)
```

Oh i wish i had the time to figure out regexes! Maybe i'll buy one as a toilet book, mmm.

Comment: Could you add a space after `12,365[_]` and before `conservatives`? I tried to demonstrate where a space would occur.

Comment: That would make it easier, but it's a regular human that provides the string, so formatting of the string is natural english loose

Comment: ask the regular human to separate fields using `;` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two-liner. Will also get Independents:

```
preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z]+)\s*([\d,]+)(?:,|$)/', $str, $matches);
$totals = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

/* total:
Array
(
    [labour] => 18909
    [liberals] => 12,365
    [conservatives] => 14,720
)
*/
```

Comment: ooya! webbiedave you are the guru!!

Comment: you should think about writing that toilet book. I'll buy a copy :)

Comment: That regex does not work fully as I test it. The alteration of `(?:,|$)` only captures '14' from the example and not '14,720' If this is the case, try dropping that for a regex of `([a-zA-Z]+)\s*([\d,]+)`

Comment: @drewk: you probably have white-space at the end of the string. In that case you can trim the string or change the regex to account for the optional white-space.

Comment: No, there is no white space that I know of. I think I just discovered a bug in a web regex tester. If I test it using 2 web regex testers, I get `14` instead of `14,720` if I have your final alteration. However, if I use Pearl with `perl -e '$_="labour 18909, liberals 12,365,conservatives 14,720"; while(/([a-zA-Z]+)\s*([\d,]+)(?:,|$)/g) { print "1=$1, 2=$2\n";}'` I get the correct answer. Regardless, I think the regex of `([a-zA-Z]+)\s*([\d,]+)`is better since the string does not need the anchor, does it?

Comment: Your suggested regex will capture the commas as well. That's why I have the last group.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a search and replace such as with sed:

```
> echo '"labour 18909, liberals 12,365,conservatives 14,720"'
    | sed -r -e 's/([0-9]),([0-9]{3})/\1\2/g'
"labour 18909, liberals 12365,conservatives 14720"
```

I'm not entirely certain what the PHP syntax would be but it basically takes a pattern consisting of a digit (X), a comma, and three other digits (Y) and replaces them with just the XY bit.

Comment: Maybe \d would be cleaner than [0-9].

Comment: @strager, sed uses posix character class specs, so you can't use `\d` iirc. Only `[:digit:]`.

Comment: @strager, that's a habit I got into long ago in my career before PCRE engines were commonplace. Not al RE engines support the extended syntax so I still find myself using ranges. I'm aware this may be risky for letters (given internationalisation) but I've never seen a problem with the digit variety. Still, you raise a good point, `\d` would probably be preferable.

Comment: Yep, that would be my approach i think. But the tiny yet vital variations in regex formatting demand a deep knowledge i've yet to master :( It would take some black art tweaking to make it work in php.

Answer (score 1):

What you want seems to be to remove commas **only** if they are *surrounded by digits*.
Sorry, I don't know the particulars of PHP regex syntax, but a couple of more abstract examples are

```
str.replace("(\d+),(\d+)", "$1$2")
s/([0-9]+),([0-9]+)/\1\2/g
```

These would get all correct numbers, but would also get something that wasn't really proper, such as "2,41,11"

Comment: y, you'd really want to flag the malformed numbers as errors rather than use them as real numbers. Still it's not bad tho

Answer (score 0):

Well, using the following regular expression you can separate the numbers from the rest:

```
labour\s*([\d,.]+),\s*liberals\s*([\d,.]+),\s*conservatives\s*([\d,.]+)
```

after all, a number clearly ends at a point where no digit follows anymore. You can then proceed with removing the commas from the values.

PowerShell demo (a little bit condensed, sorry):

```
PS Home:\> $s -match 'labour\s*(?<labour>[\d,.]+),\s*liberals\s*(?<liberals>[\d,.]+),\s*conservatives\s*(?<conservatives>[\d,.]+)' |
               Out-Null
PS Home:\> "Labour: {0}`nLiberals: {1}`nConservatives: {2}" -f `
           ($Matches['labour'],$Matches['liberals'],$Matches['conservatives'] |
               foreach { $_ -replace ',' })

Labour: 18909
Liberals: 12365
Conservatives: 14720
```

Comment: wow regex is truly the jackson pollock of programming syntax!

Comment: You didn't see APL or J, then.

Answer (score -1):

In a former life, I did a lot of data processing like this, except there were 100's of millions of records taking days to process.

I always found it was a wise to follow this strategy

1. Know you data

   . The customer will always say their data is perfect, well formed and correct

   . It invariably is a pile of steaming dodo poop.
2. Define the rules for the data, sometimes it is easier to define what the data isn't
3. Use a regex or even macro search and replace within and editor to find where the data breaks  the rules
4. Repair, request new data sets, discard data
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 till the data is clean
6. Now think about the format of the data, can the regex matching be simplified by some simple manipulation of the data

   . For example in you case, replacing a comma followed by multiple white space with a single comma

   .  Then strip every comma surrounded by numbers

   . strip multiple white space (leave single white space)

   . strip white space immediately before and alpha character
7. Define rules for this new data set and make sure it's clean

   . this can now include range checking on the numeric data

   . even more complex rules
8. Now your data looks like "labour 18909,liberals 12365,conservatives 14720"
9. Build you import tool for this new data set (the easy bit)
10. Make sure you have a repeatable system for 1..9 as the customer will want a simple change or just this extra little bit they need right now.